# Let V, W, and U be vector spaces over a field F, and let f,g: V → W and h,j: W → U be linear maps.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let V, W, and U be vector spaces over a field F, and let f,g: V → W and h,j: W → U be linear maps. Prove that

(a) h ◦ (f + g) = (h ◦ f) + (h ◦ g)
(b) (h + j) ◦ f= (h ◦ f) + (j ◦ f)

I think I get the idea of this problem, but I really don't know where to start. The question basically asks to deduce for every vector space V, the set of all linear transformations from V to V (i.e. Hom(V,V)) forms a ring with point-wise addition and composition.

Comment: And you also will want to prove it point wise, which is not hard if you just plug in and evaluate. The important point is that e. g. addition of linear maps is defined pointeise

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Start with the **definition** of *compositions* and the *addition* of maps.

For instance,
$$
\begin{align}
(h\circ(f+g))(x)
&=h((f+g)(x))
&(\textrm{$F\circ G(x):=F(G(x))$})
\\
&=h(f(x)+g(x))
&(\textrm{$(F+G)(x):=F(x)+G(x)$})\\
&=\cdots
\end{align}
$$

Then use the linearity.